# Help with SQLITE query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables Task and TaskTag and Tag as below..

```
CREATE TABLE Task (task_id text PRIMARY KEY, subject text);
CREATE TABLE TaskTag (task_tag_id text PRIMARY KEY, task_id text, tag_id text);
CREATE TABLE Tag (tag_id text PRIMARY KEY, tag text);
```

I want to find a record in `Task` where there are two matching tags: tag1, tag2

How would the SQL look, I have tried but I can't get this to work using AND, but can using OR..

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Task 
  JOIN TaskTag ON Task.task_id = TaskTag.task_id 
  JOIN Tag ON TaskTag.tag_id = Tag.tag_id 
 WHERE tag = "tag1" 
   AND tag = "tag2"
```

Comment: @Joe Tuskan: Please don't revert to original wording -- it's a waste of our votes, and provides no value.  Please be more judicious when editing in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM Task 
    JOIN TaskTag ON Task.task_id = TaskTag.task_id 
    JOIN Tag ON TaskTag.tag_id = Tag.tag_id 
   WHERE tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2')
GROUP BY Task.task_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = 2
```

The `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` needs to equal the number of `IN` parameters, or you risk seeing false positives (IE duplicates of tag1 would count as 2, etc).